# Pioneer 3 keyboard teleoperation

Tags: ros, pioneer, keyboard-teleop

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello!

I'm a spanish student and I'm doing my career final project and I'm being introduced in robotics. I've been working with some other ros packages to try to get how it works. I'm working with a Pioneer 3 and I need to teleoperate it by keyboard but I do have problems to find a package which can help me (I'm sorry because of my ingorance). teleop-base seems to be deprecated anf I have problems to install the erratic_teleop one. Can any of you help me please?

Thank you in advance for your attention.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12134/pioneer-3-keyboard-teleoperation/) by [Julio](https://answers.ros.org/users/1458/julio/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2011-11-28

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [arebgun](https://answers.ros.org/users/18/arebgun/) on 2011-11-29**:
what kind of problems do you have installing erratic_teleop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
You can use [ROSARIA](http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROSARIA) for this purpose. You can use the teleop_base package for teleoperating the same. If anyone knows better package pls do update here.

Thanks,
Karthik

---

Originally posted by [karthik](https://answers.ros.org/users/961/karthik/) with karma: 2831 on 2011-11-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Julio](https://answers.ros.org/users/1458/julio/) on 2011-11-28**:
Thanks a lot! =)